# web site regression testing software used across multiple site

Tags: testing, selenium, regression, moodle

I'm an intern at a company, We are beginning to start thinking about how to automate our product.   We use a moodle based site, we have around 20 sites.  We would like to find a regression testing software that would aid us in testing all the sites (regression testing), where the test cases can be used across multiple sites.  I tried using selenium and I was not the greatest because of embedded wysiwyg editors.  I also looked at ranorex and it had a harder time moving across multiple sites.

These sites have the same site path

Comment: Well, considering you tagged selenium, you're going to get a lot of pro-selenium comments.  However, I would recommend mentioning some of the requirements/functionality you want.  (Besides the embedded wysiwyg editor, which you should be able to automate with selenium).  Selenium does just fine with multi-site automation.

Comment: I recently heard of [BugBuster](http://bugbuster.com/). Unfortunately never used it but it looks interesting.

Comment: I have tried selenium a lot, I'm using the tests as Junit tests and it is not practical on testing the UI from the users side, because of how junit tests are geared toward development.  I'm open to all options.

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand which type of automation tests do you want to perform.

Do you want to perform UI level tests ? In that case I would use Selenium which is the most popular UI automation tests tool. The tool is really flexible since the code of your tests will reside on a known programming language (C#,Java,Python,etc)

Maybe you want to perform tests on the API level, in that case you have other possible tools like JMeter, SoapUI, some python libraries, among others...

Which kind of automation tests are you trying to develop ?